# Program using pointer and dynamic storage to pass around a character string of unknown size at startup

Tags: c, string, programming-languages, dynamic-allocation, calloc

This is my assignment:

> Write a program and the following functions using dynamic storage to
>   manipulate the character strings.
>
> a. A function to input an unknown number of character strings of
>   unknown length (max 80) and store each string in dynamic storage.
>
> b. A function to output each character string and its corresponding
>   length in terms of the number of characters.
>
> The program should begin by reading the number of character strings to
>   be processed and allocating dynamic storage for the pointers.

My code is below. This version compiles fine but breaks when trying to get output.

Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int funcinput (char **, int *,char *);
void funcoutput (char **, int *);

int main()
{
   char c;
   int *n;
   char *ptr;
   char **userinput=calloc(*n,80);

   funcinput (userinput,&*n,&*ptr);
   funcoutput (userinput,&*n);
}


int funcinput(char **userinput, int *n, char *ptr)
{   
  char c;
  int counter =0;
  int max=0;

  printf("How many items are in your list\n");
  scanf("%d",&*n);

  max = *n;

  ptr = (char*)calloc(*n,80);

  printf("Enter your list, each item can be a max of 80 characters long:\n");
  for (counter=0;counter<*n;counter++)
  {
   scanf("%80s",&userinput[c]);  
  } 
  return;
 }

void funcoutput (char **userinput,int *n)
{
char c;
int counter1=0;
int max1=0;

max1 = *n;

printf ("You entered %d strings of charectors\n",*n);
printf ("The following is the list you entered \n");
for(counter1=0;counter1<max1;counter1++)
{
    printf("\n%-80s         \n",*userinput[c]);
}
return;
}
```

Comment: `char **userinput=calloc(*n,80);` : `n` uninitialize. also meybe `char **userinput=calloc(*n, sizeof(char*));`

Comment: I know when it's midnight for me. I have no idea when it's midnight for you, so I removed all that. If you want help 'after midnight', post 'after midnight'.

Comment: Things like this: `&*n` are a subtle indication that this question will have far more to do with language basics than of a specific problem.  There are a multitude of errors in this, several compounded by others, and only some of them having anything to do with dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **funcinput (int *size /* out */);
void funcoutput (char **out_array, int size);

int main(){
    //char c;//unused
    int n;
    //char *ptr;//unused
    char **userinput = funcinput(&n);

    funcoutput(userinput, n);
    //deallocate
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        free(userinput[i]);
    }
    free(userinput);
    return 0;
}

char **funcinput(int *n){// n : output size
    int counter =0;
    int max=0;

    printf("How many items are in your list\n");
    scanf("%d", n);

    max = *n;

    char **userinput = calloc(max, sizeof(char*));

    printf("Enter your list, each item can be a max of 80 characters long:\n");
    for (counter=0;counter < max;counter++){
        userinput[counter] = calloc(80, sizeof(char));
        if(1!=scanf("%79s", userinput[counter])){//spaces not includes
            free(userinput[counter]);
            break;
        }
    }
    *n = counter;
    return userinput;
}

void funcoutput (char **userinput,int n){
    int counter=0;
    int max=n;

    printf ("You entered %d strings\n", n);
    printf ("The following is the list you entered \n");
    for(counter=0;counter<max;counter++){
        printf("%s\n", userinput[counter]);//%-80s : Probably not necessary
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you none of my text had gone over free() yet though I have seen it other online examples. Can you suggest any tutorials on C, I have purchases other books, and read my textbook, but this is an 8 week course so need to learn fast? Specifically on pointers and dynamic memory allocation (calloc, malloc, realloc).